# Linux + Dynamically inserted Java applet = Error calling method on NPObject

Tags: java, php, javascript, linux, japplet

I have an html page, where I dynamically create applet's HTML code and insert it into the page with with javascript.
After that I call some applet's methods.
Everything works fine in other OS's, and user to work in some Linux machines before.
But now under Linux I get a very strange and too general error message:
`Error calling method on NPObject!`
I really don't understand what is going on.
When creating applet code not dynamically (not wit JS, just insert it into HTML in the template), it works fine.
What could this be?
Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could this be?

The latest in a long line of applet/JS/browser/CSS interaction bugs.  Here are the hits for [applet liveconnect](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=applet+liveconnect&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=bugdatabase.sun&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=#hl=en&lr=&tbo=d&as_qdr=all&q=applet+liveconnect+site%3abugs.sun.com&oq=applet+liveconnect+site%3abugs.sun.com&gs_l=serp.3...49069.51894.0.53059.5.5.0.0.0.0.745.2661.4-3j1j1.5.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.zJfIAMEjGqw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=303f6dd17190fca9&bpcl=39650382&biw=1030&bih=975).

> Any thoughts?

Don't fight it, but instead use another strategy.  I suggest:

1. Load the applet at page load.
2. Hide the applet using CSS (move it off the visible page, or make the size small).
3. Trigger JS that interacts with the CSS To reveal the applet.

Comment: re. winning - I wouldn't be putting bets on it.  Especially when you 'fix' it and some other version of some browser on some platform is released next week that breaks it all over again.  That is the nature of applet/JVM/browser/JS interaction.